# didn't get loop while without clear condition ```while(y)```

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I don't get the meaning of this y inside while loop:

```
function gcd_two_numbers(x, y) {
  if ((typeof x !== 'number') || (typeof y !== 'number')) 
    return false;
  x = Math.abs(x);
  y = Math.abs(y);
  while(y) {
    var t = y;
    y = x % y;
    x = t;
  }
  return x;
}
```

Comment: y is the condition being tested for the loop to run ... while y is truthy, the loop continues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while` loops don't exclusively require boolean values. `while` simply tests if a value is truthy or falsy. For numeric values, 0 is considered falsy and will stop the while loop, while every other number is considered truthy and will continue the while loop. The same applies to if statements. In this case, the while loop will run until y is 0.

Comment: thank you, I am new to programming and that was helpful